# VBA webscraping English premier League form

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to scrape form data(last 6 games played) but its not coming out the way I want.The form column shows green (Win), Orange(Draw) and Lose(Red).I would like to see the team first and the form like below:

for example,
Liverpool WWWWDL

Below is the code that I have used

```
Sub ELPForm()
 
    'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object
    Dim y As Integer
 
    'start a new browser instance
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'make browser visible
    objIE.Visible = False
 
    'navigate to page with needed data
    objIE.navigate "https://www.soccerstats.com/latest.asp?league=england"
    'wait for page to load
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
    y = 1
 
  
    For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("btable").getElementsByTagName("tr")
        'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
        Debug.Print ele.textContent
        'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(10).textContent
        'increment row counter by 1
        y = y + 1
    'repeat until last ele has been evaluated
    Next
 
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The page uses the ID *btable* multiple times. The HTML standard is not adhered to, because an ID must be unique. You get the right table because it is the first one with the ID *btable*. I would work with *getElementsByClassName("odd")* and process the first 20 elements of the NodeCollection.

As you can see, the *1* and *Liverpool* are read out correctly and entered into the table. Also the index 10 for your desired tr-tag is correct. But what you want to know is **not in the text**, but in the first div-tag of the 10th td-tag of a tr-tag.

So you have to read the first div-tag in every 10th td-tag:

```
<div>
  <div class='dgreen'></div>
  <div class='dgreen'></div>
  <div class='dgreen'></div>
  <div class='dgreen'></div>
  <div class='dorange'></div>
  <div class='dgreen'></div>
</div>
```

You then use this with each div-tag contained in it in a for-loop and query in each of the 6 loop passes with *Select Case* which of the three possible colors is set as class attribute. You process the result as you need it. After 6 loops you will have exactly the list you want. I haven't tried it, but I assume *class* is just an attribute that you can process with the *getAttribute()* method.

Best regards

Zwenn

Comment: Hi Zwenn. Thanks for the reply. Am still new with vba which is my biggest challenge and am completely lost in terms of how I would execute as per your explanation above. I googled a lot and so far haven't found some code that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

It's late in Germany but you get what you want with the folowing macro. If you don't need the coloring of the result string comment the lines out.

The macro code is not realy long but there are many comments and HTML code samples to understand what the macro is doing:

```
Sub ELPForm()

Dim browser As Object
Dim url As String
Dim nodesAllOdd As Object
Dim nodeSingleOdd As Object
Dim nodeAllCellsOfTheGotTableRow As Object
Dim nodeTableCellWithLastSixResults As Object
Dim nodeLastSixResults As Object
Dim nodesColors As Object
Dim nodeSingleColor As Object

Dim targetTable As String
Dim indexOdd As Long
Dim indexOddLowerBound As Long
Dim indexOddUpperBound As Long
Dim tableRow As Long
Dim lastSixResults As String
Dim charIndex As Byte

  'Table for imported data
  targetTable = "Sheet1"

  'First row for output
  tableRow = 1

  'Page with needed data
  url = "https://www.soccerstats.com/latest.asp?league=england"

  'Css index "odd" from bottom to top for the relevant table
  'Adjust the boundaries when the table is moved
  'That is the reason I prefered the "odd" class and not the
  'table ID you used
  indexOddLowerBound = 0
  indexOddUpperBound = 19

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = False
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Get all html nodes with the css class odd
  Set nodesAllOdd = browser.document.getElementsByClassName("odd")

  'Check if there is a node collection
  If Not nodesAllOdd Is Nothing Then
    'The firt 20 elements of the node collection are relevant at this time
    'In the future it can be the tables will be other ordered. All you have
    'to do then is to set the borders for the the new order
    'Now we go for the first 20 elements by a loop from 0 to 19 (by node
    'collection index) if there are more than 19 elements (by real count
    'of elements by the property "length")
    If nodesAllOdd.Length > 19 Then
      For indexOdd = indexOddLowerBound To indexOddUpperBound
        'Get the current "odd" node
        'All 20 single nodes looks like this example:
        '
        '<tr class='odd' height='24'>
        '  <td bgcolor='#12bc3b' height='22' align='center'>
        '    <b>1</b>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='left' width='110'> &nbsp;<a href='team.asp?league=england&stats=u40-liverpool' title='Liverpool stats' target='_top'>Liverpool</a>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='green'>11</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'> 10 </td>
        '  <td align='center'> 1 </td>
        '  <td align='center'> 0 </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='blue'>25</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='red'>9</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='gray' size='1'>+16</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center' bgcolor='#dedede'>
        '    <b>31</b>
        '  </td>
        '  <td style='padding-left:10px;'>
        '    <a href='#' class='tooltip2'>
        '      <div>
        '        <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '        <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '        <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '        <div class='dorange'></div>
        '        <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '        <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '      </div>
        '      <span>
        '        <div style='text-align:left;'>
        '          <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        '            <tr>
        '              <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <font color='gray' size='1'>22 Sep</font>
        '              </td>
        '              <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'> Chelsea - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '              </td>
        '              <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b>1-2</b>
        '              </td>
        '            </tr>
        '            <tr>
        '              <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <font color='gray' size='1'>28 Sep</font>
        '              </td>
        '              <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'> Sheffield Utd - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '              </td>
        '              <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b>0-1</b>
        '              </td>
        '            </tr>
        '            <tr>
        '              <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <font color='gray' size='1'>5 Oct</font>
        '              </td>
        '              <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b> Liverpool </b> - Leicester City </td>
        '              <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b>2-1</b>
        '              </td>
        '            </tr>
        '            <tr>
        '              <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #FFFFBF;'>
        '                <font color='gray' size='1'>20 Oct</font>
        '              </td>
        '              <td style='background-color: #FFFFBF;'> Manchester Utd - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '              </td>
        '              <td align='center' style='background-color: #FFFFBF;'>
        '                <b>1-1</b>
        '              </td>
        '            </tr>
        '            <tr>
        '              <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <font color='gray' size='1'>27 Oct</font>
        '              </td>
        '              <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b> Liverpool </b> - Tottenham </td>
        '              <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b>2-1</b>
        '              </td>
        '            </tr>
        '            <tr>
        '              <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <font color='gray' size='1'>2 Nov</font>
        '              </td>
        '              <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'> Aston Villa - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '              </td>
        '              <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '                <b>1-2</b>
        '              </td>
        '            </tr>
        '          </table>
        '        </div>
        '      </span>
        '    </a>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='black'>2.82</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='red'>2.75</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='green'>18%</font>
        '  </td>
        '  <td align='center'>
        '    <font color='red'>0%</font>
        '  </td>
        '</tr>
        Set nodeSingleOdd = nodesAllOdd(indexOdd)

        'The information we need are in certain cells of the got table row
        'So at first we need all cells of the got table row
        Set nodeAllCellsOfTheGotTableRow = nodeSingleOdd.getElementsByTagName("td")

        'We need the first table cell for the team place in the table of the league
        '<td bgcolor='#12bc3b' height='22' align='center'>
        '  <b>1</b>
        '</td>
        '
        'Node collection index for the first element is 0
        'We place the place of the team in thie first column of the current row in the table
        Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 1).Value = nodeAllCellsOfTheGotTableRow(0).innertext

        'We need the second table cell for the team name
        '  <td align='left' width='110'> &nbsp;<a href='team.asp?league=england&stats=u40-liverpool' title='Liverpool stats' target='_top'>Liverpool</a>
        '  </td>
        '
        'Node collection index for the second element is 1
        'We place the team name in the second column of the current row in the table
        Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 2).Value = nodeAllCellsOfTheGotTableRow(1).innertext

        'And our patient. The 11th cell of the current table row
        '<td style='padding-left:10px;'>
        '  <a href='#' class='tooltip2'>
        '    <div>
        '      <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '      <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '      <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '      <div class='dorange'></div>
        '      <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '      <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '    </div>
        '    <span>
        '      <div style='text-align:left;'>
        '        <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        '          <tr>
        '            <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <font color='gray' size='1'>22 Sep</font>
        '            </td>
        '            <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'> Chelsea - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '            </td>
        '            <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b>1-2</b>
        '            </td>
        '          </tr>
        '          <tr>
        '            <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <font color='gray' size='1'>28 Sep</font>
        '            </td>
        '            <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'> Sheffield Utd - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '            </td>
        '            <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b>0-1</b>
        '            </td>
        '          </tr>
        '          <tr>
        '            <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <font color='gray' size='1'>5 Oct</font>
        '            </td>
        '            <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b> Liverpool </b> - Leicester City </td>
        '            <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b>2-1</b>
        '            </td>
        '          </tr>
        '          <tr>
        '            <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #FFFFBF;'>
        '              <font color='gray' size='1'>20 Oct</font>
        '            </td>
        '            <td style='background-color: #FFFFBF;'> Manchester Utd - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '            </td>
        '            <td align='center' style='background-color: #FFFFBF;'>
        '              <b>1-1</b>
        '            </td>
        '          </tr>
        '          <tr>
        '            <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <font color='gray' size='1'>27 Oct</font>
        '            </td>
        '            <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b> Liverpool </b> - Tottenham </td>
        '            <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b>2-1</b>
        '            </td>
        '          </tr>
        '          <tr>
        '            <td align='right' height='18' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <font color='gray' size='1'>2 Nov</font>
        '            </td>
        '            <td style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'> Aston Villa - <b> Liverpool </b>
        '            </td>
        '            <td align='center' style='background-color: #D7EFBE;'>
        '              <b>1-2</b>
        '            </td>
        '          </tr>
        '        </table>
        '      </div>
        '    </span>
        '  </a>
        '</td>
        '
        'Node collection index for the 11th element is 10
        Set nodeTableCellWithLastSixResults = nodeAllCellsOfTheGotTableRow(10)

        'The desired information are the results of the last six games in form of win, draw or lost
        'We see a lot of information in the HTML code obove. For the needed one, we need only the first div tag
        '<div>
        '  <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '  <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '  <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '  <div class='dorange'></div>
        '  <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '  <div class='dgreen'></div>
        '</div>
        '
        'The needed div Tag is the first one
        'We get it by the tag name and get the first div element by the index 0 of the node collecton
        Set nodeLastSixResults = nodeTableCellWithLastSixResults.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)

        'There is no text but three different colors for win, draw or lost
        'dgreen  = win
        'dorange = draw
        'dred    = lost
        '
        'We make a node collection of the div tags inside the last got div tag
        Set nodesColors = nodeLastSixResults.getElementsByTagName("div")

        'This is what we have now in our node collection
        '<div class='dgreen'></div>
        '<div class='dgreen'></div>
        '<div class='dgreen'></div>
        '<div class='dorange'></div>
        '<div class='dgreen'></div>
        '<div class='dgreen'></div>
        '
        'We get all colors in a loop
        For Each nodeSingleColor In nodesColors
          Select Case nodeSingleColor.getAttribute("class")
            Case "dgreen": lastSixResults = lastSixResults & "W"
            Case "dorange": lastSixResults = lastSixResults & "D"
            Case "dred": lastSixResults = lastSixResults & "L"
          End Select
        Next nodeSingleColor

        'Write the result string to the table
        Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Value = lastSixResults

        'Coloring the result string with the same colors like on the page
        'and set the proportional font Courier New for better eye traking
        For charIndex = 1 To Len(lastSixResults)
          Select Case Mid(lastSixResults, charIndex, 1)
            Case "W" 'Green 51, 153, 51
              Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Characters(Start:=charIndex, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(51, 153, 51)
              Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Characters(Start:=charIndex, Length:=1).Font.Name = "Courier New"
            Case "D" 'Orange 255, 181, 108
              Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Characters(Start:=charIndex, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 181, 108)
              Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Characters(Start:=charIndex, Length:=1).Font.Name = "Courier New"
            Case "L" 'Red 255, 0, 0
              Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Characters(Start:=charIndex, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
              Sheets(targetTable).Cells(tableRow, 3).Characters(Start:=charIndex, Length:=1).Font.Name = "Courier New"
          End Select
        Next charIndex

        'Reset result string
        lastSixResults = ""

        'Next Excel table row for the next team
        tableRow = tableRow + 1
      Next indexOdd
    Else
      MsgBox "No node collection with at least 20 css odd elements."
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "Wrong page. No relevant tables found"
  End If

  'Clean up
  browser.Quit
  Set browser = Nothing
  Set nodesAllOdd = Nothing
  Set nodeSingleOdd = Nothing
  Set nodeAllCellsOfTheGotTableRow = Nothing
  Set nodeTableCellWithLastSixResults = Nothing
  Set nodeLastSixResults = Nothing
  Set nodesColors = Nothing
  Set nodeSingleColor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Best regards

Zwenn

Comment: Hi Zwenn. This is perfect. Exactly the way I want it. Thank you so much for your help , I really appreciate. High 5 to you.

Comment: Hi vincy, that's good :-) You can vote my answer as usefull and as solution. Thats the real high five ;-)